# How to grant user permission to certain folders using Client Object Model?

Tags: client-object-model, permissions, folder

So far I am able to grant user certain permission with the following code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://myRealURL");
Principal user = context.Web.EnsureUser(@"myLoginAccout");

RoleDefinition readDef = context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Read");
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefCollection = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context);
roleDefCollection.Add(readDef);
RoleAssignment newRoleAssignment = context.Web.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleDefCollection);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Anyway the code above works fine, now my task is to add the user permission only to certain folders with C# code. For example, under `Libraries`, I have a `library` called `JZhu`, and inside `JZhu`, I have two folders `folder1` and `folder2`. Is it possible to change the access permission on these two folders with `Client Object Model`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new RoleDefinitionBinding, object set the type of permissions to it and add it as parameter to RoleAssignments of list item:

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
    using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

    namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
    {
        class BreakSecurityInheritanceAddUser
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                string siteUrl = "Your site url";
                ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("JZhu");
                var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.SiteGroups);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                GroupCollection oSiteCollectionGroups= clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
                foreach (Group grp in oSiteCollectionGroups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(grp.Title);
                    if (grp.Title == "My group")
                    {
                        oGroup=gpr;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var folder = GetListItemFolder(item); //get Folder
                    Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
                    if (folder.Name=="Folder 1" || folder.Name=="Folder 2")
                    {
                        item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                        RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);

                        //set role type
                        collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader));
                        //oGroup - your group
                        item.RoleAssignments.Add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            private static Folder GetListItemFolder(ListItem listItem)
            {
                var folderUrl = (string)listItem["FileDirRef"];
                var parentFolder = listItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
                listItem.Context.Load(parentFolder);
                listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery();
                return parentFolder;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not have a `list` in my question, what should I put in `clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List Name");`?

Comment: where are your folders? They have to be inside document library

Comment: I have added a screen shot. Have a look. The folders are inside library called `JZhu`

Comment: @HashMap updated my answer

Comment: @line `item.RoleAssignments.Add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);`, what is `oGroup`? My program currently does not complie and has red line under `oGroup`

Comment: @HashMap ofc, you have to put there the group that u want to add :). Read permission on the folder for which group!? I updated the answer, now you can get the group by name.

Comment: Thanks for the constant help. I am getting there :) What `[FileDirRef"] `mean in `var folderUrl = (string)listItem["FileDirRef"];`?

Comment: Just to get the item url. To get a field u use this syntax: item ["column name"]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new RoleDefinitionBinding, object set the type of permissions to it and add it as parameter to RoleAssignments of list item:

Code Sample:

```
using (clientContext = new ClientContext(sharepont URL))
            {
                try
                {
                    var securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in Password)
                    {
                        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                    }
            
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, securePassword);
                    WebClient = clientContext.Web;

                    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                    var rootfolder = list.RootFolder;// find root folder 
                    clientContext.Load(rootfolder);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    string fpath=rootfolder.ServerRelativeUrl+ "Your folder path using "/"; //eg /folderName/A1/A1

                    Principal user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(UserName);// UserName : emailid or user name
                    var folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(fpath);
                    var roleDefinition = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Editor);  //get Reader role
                    var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext) { roleDefinition };
                    folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);  //set folder unique permissions
                    folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleBindings);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(fpath + "-  folder grantted");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }  
            }
```